# circular reference marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I'm having a problem with a circular reference in my marionette.js application..

The problem is:

App.js creates the router with an controller, and that controller requires the app.js again so it can add the views to the regions.. As you can see below (the controller) when i print the `Application` it returns undefined because of the circulare reference..

controller.js:

```
define(
['app', 'views/ProjectItemView'],
function (Application, ProjectItemView)
{
    'use strict';
            console.log(Application); // undefined

    return Marionette.Controller.extend({
        showProjects : function()
        {
            Application.main.show(new ProjectItemView());
            console.log('project');
        }
    });
}
);
```

router.js:

```
   define
    (
        ['marionette'],
        function(Marionette)
        {
            'use strict';

            return Marionette.AppRouter.extend
            (
                {
                    appRoutes:
                    {
                        'dashboard/projects' : 'showProjects'
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

app.js

```
define
(
    [
        'backbone', 'marionette', 'jquery', 'routers/DashboardRouter', 'controllers/DashboardController',
        'views/dashboard/Header'
    ],
    function(Backbone, Marionette, $, DashboardRouter, DashboardController, Header)
    {
        'use strict';

        var app = new Marionette.Application();

        app.addRegions({
            header: '#header',
            main: '#main',
        });

        app.header.show(new Header());

        app.on('initialize:after', function () {
            Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
            app.router = new DashboardRouter({
                controller : DashboardController
            });
        });

        $(document).on("click", "a[href^='/']", function(event)
        {
            var href = $(event.currentTarget).attr('href');
            console.log(href);

            event.preventDefault();
            app.router.navigate(href, {trigger: true});
            return false;
        });

        return app;
    }
);
```

Now what is the best way to solve this problem? I'm totally new to this so i don't really know what the best practice is..

Also is it correct that I add the views in my controller? Or should i do that somewhere else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please post your app file?

Comment: yes i have added it, please have a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should pass a region to the controller at the time to instanciate it, you definitly need to move your code. I have a sample application working but not with require, however the concept of creating a region in the controller and passing a region from the main app to it can be demostraded here.

```
 App.addInitializer(function () {
    var controller = new BookStoreController({region: App.mainRegion});
    layout = new CatalogLayout();
    controller.region.show(layout);
    var router = new Router({controller:controller});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/hsrv7/11/

Hope that helps.

Comment: so basically just pass the region as an argument of the controller? I'm going to try that

Comment: this works fine, however i'm waiting to accept this answer till i have some more information on the other answer about the modules.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, essentially, you have Router depends on App and Controller depends on App.

If that is the case, you just break them into three modules, App, Router, and Controller.
Then define ['app',...] in both Router and Controller modules.
[Here](https://github.com/cardinal27513/jquerymobile-marionette) is some other basic code structure that I used for JMQ.

Updated:
From [Using-marionette-with-requirejs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs), it also discusses about "Avoiding Circular Dependencies"

Comment: With modules you mean https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md ? And when do i have to call those modules than, can you add some more information because i don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: I referred to requirejs module, you can read it here as how to use requirejs with marionette. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs  In this wiki, it also discusses about circular dependence as you are facing.. Hope this help.

Comment: Ok thank you, that is what i also tried and worked, but I thought it was maybe a structural problem in my app. Thanks though, but i'm going to accept the other answer as i'm using that solution. Gave it a +1

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ProjectView into a Marionette Module.

Please refer to https://github.com/mallim/backbone_examples/blob/master/app/scripts/cats/module.js for an example of such technqiue.

Hope this helps.